# How can I combine a Mono and a Flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am creating a Flux of Product and a Mono Category object that needs to be applied to the Products because all they all all to be grouped into the same category. I am attempting to add the category to each Product like this.

```java
     Flux<Product> products = productRepository.findAllById(productCodes);
     Mono<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(productCodes.get(0));
     
     The category for all these products should be set as:

     //If these were a list of products i.e List<Product> productList and Category was 
     //not a Mono I would set them like this:
 
     productList.forEach( product -> product.setCategory(category));
```

Since the respective repositories return Mono and Flux respectively, I am unsure how to do that use the reactive framework as I am very new to it. Can someone please show me how to achieve this using reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are many ways to implement this.

Here is an example where you apply function with `flatMap()` to every element of your product flux. This function uses your category `Mono` to to set the category to the product.

```java
productsFlux.flatMap(product -> categoryMono.map(category -> {
    product.setCategory(category);
    return product;
}));
```

Or vice versa using `flatMapMany()` on you category Mono:

```java
categoryMono.flatMapMany(category -> productsFlux.map(product -> {
    product.setCategory(category);
    return product;
}));
```

Or you can turn your category `Mono` into hot-never-ending flux with cache and do `Flux.zip()` on your products flux and category flux, like this: (I would prefer this option since it is better to ensure that db call for category called only once)

```java
Flux<String> categoryHotFlux = categoryMono.cache().repeat();

Flux.zip(productsFlux, categoryHotFlux)
        .map(tuple -> {
            Product product = tuple.getT1();
            Category category = tuple.getT2();
            product.setCategory(category);
            return product;
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try using the best option you specified. I'm really grateful

Comment: Nothing seems to work except I add a subscribe to the code.  Also I am trying to save the product to the products collection  and the category to an audit table. However, neither update works. When I include logging statements it says it save but that doesn't happen

Comment: Honestly, I didn't think this was worth to mention, but of course, reactive has a general rule - nothing happens until you subsrcibe. This is the basics of reactive paradigm, you should learn more about it. Also the reason I didn't mention that is because you haven't given any context information about your code (is it a test? is it a service method? who calls this method? what that method should return? etc.). Also, you didn't mention anything about saving to db, this is another question, I suppose. The code I provided exactly answers the question asked.

Comment: I'm sorry I did add a subscribe which I should have mentioned that